# Connecting to Exchange with Golang

Tags: go, smtp, exchange-server

How do I connect with Exchange server with Go? I have tried:

```
func main() {

to := "first.last@acme.com"
from := "me@acme.com"
password := "myKey"
subject := "Subject Here"
msg := "Message here"

emailTemplate := `To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
`
body := fmt.Sprintf(emailTemplate, to, subject, msg)
auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", from, password, "smtp.office365.com")
err := smtp.SendMail(
    "smtp.office365.com:587",
    auth,
    from,
    []string{to},
    []byte(body),
)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
}
```

This code returns:

```
504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type
```

I'm porting over Python/Django code, and it has a setting where I mark have to declare:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Perhaps something similar in Go?

Comment: Take a look at this example: https://gist.github.com/chrisgillis/10888032

Answer (score 8):

Office does not support AUTH PLAIN after August 2017. [Ref](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outlook-com-no-longer-supports-auth-plain-authentication-07f7d5e9-1697-465f-84d2-4513d4ff0145). However, it does support AUTH LOGIN. AUTH LOGIN does not have a native Golang implementation but here is a working one:

```
type loginAuth struct {
    username, password string
}

// LoginAuth is used for smtp login auth
func LoginAuth(username, password string) smtp.Auth {
    return &loginAuth{username, password}
}

func (a *loginAuth) Start(server *smtp.ServerInfo) (string, []byte, error) {
    return "LOGIN", []byte(a.username), nil
}

func (a *loginAuth) Next(fromServer []byte, more bool) ([]byte, error) {
    if more {
        switch string(fromServer) {
        case "Username:":
            return []byte(a.username), nil
        case "Password:":
            return []byte(a.password), nil
        default:
            return nil, errors.New("Unknown from server")
        }
    }
    return nil, nil
}
```

Replace this auth implementation with the `stmp.PlainAuth` from Golang lib and it should work accordingly.